# Index match - looking up partial string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to assign labels to a description based on looking up a partial string with index match.

Column A: Description of the product (this data exists)

Column B: (this is where the formula is plugged in)

Column G: labels that are assigned to the descriptions in column B

I use the following formula to assign the labels to the descriptions from B2:B7
`=INDEX(G:G;MATCH("*"&A2&"*";A:A;0))` and then drag down.

However, I get the following result:
[image: Result I get]

When I want to get following result:

[image: Result wanted]

Can anyone see what I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=INDEX($G$2:$G$4,MATCH(1,SEARCH("*"&$G$2:$G$4&"*",$A2),0))`
This is an array formula and needs entered with `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`

The search part will return 1 if the value is found. The position of the 1 in the search array is equal to the row number. Match searches for the position of the 1 in the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You might could to this instead, so long as your first 6 characters of A are unique:

```
=INDEX(G:G;MATCH("*"&LEFT(A2,6)&"*";A:A;0))
```

Or you can make it 5, 7, ... whatever you feel will remain unique but minimal.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either - same result.

Comment: Must be something with 2010 - sorry.